# Multiple tags for structure

Tags: discussion, tags

I was writing a question (now aborted because I found a duplicate) and noticed that we have two tags for the same thing.

- [structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) - "How to put together elements of a story or sentence."
- [sentence-structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure) - "This tag should be used for questions about structuring your sentences in certain genres or for certain characters in your writing."

[sentence-structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure) is a much newer tag so I am wondering if it was created to be more specific than the old tag. This is a trend we have seen across other tags (Book mostly replaced by novel for instance).

However, there is only one [question that uses both tags](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure+structure) which makes me think they are actually duplicates and users are simply using the one they find first.

**What should we do with these tags?**

1. Make them synonyms, leave [structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) as the main tag. Generally sub-string tag matches should be handled by the UI but this case may be an exception.
2. Change [structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) to "story-structure" and have two tags. This may be too close to [plot](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) and then be a synonym of that.
3. Something else?

Comment: About #1, generally tag synonyms are not used for substring matches, as those are already matched by the UI.

Comment: @aCVn That's true. However it also should have prevented one of these tags from existing in the first place. Given that they *do* exist would it be a misuse to make the synonyms to clean them up?

Comment: I feel "structure" is more about the Whole Project, like, "Would it be lopsided if only the first third of the book has flashbacks?"  Sentence-structure would be more "Can I use run-ons in first person POV to express the hyper nature of this character, or will it look like I (the author) just don't know what I'm doing?"

Comment: @April Would a tag wiki edit for [tag:structure] to match that usage be enough? Then retagged sentence structure questions that use the wrong tag.

Comment: The structure of a story (or other work) is *very* different from sentence structure.  I'm willing to listen to arguments about how either (or both) of these is covered by another tag, but they really aren't the same as each other.  I would change the wiki to be less confusing though.

Comment: I don't know the best way to handle it as far as tagging goes, just that the concepts seem distinct to me.  (The whole wiki/synonym thing here loses me at times.)